# Return in generator together with yield

Tags: python, generator, python-3.3

In Python 2 it used to cause an error when `return` occurred together with `yield` inside a function definition. But for this code in Python 3.3:

```
def f():
  return 3
  yield 2
  
x = f()
print(x.__next__())
```

there is no error that `return` is used in function with `yield`. However when the function `__next__` is called then there is thrown exception `StopIteration`. Why there is not just returned value `3`? Is this `return` somehow ignored?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This is a new feature in Python 3.3. Much like `return` in a generator has long been equivalent to `raise StopIteration()`, `return <something>` in a generator is now equivalent to `raise StopIteration(<something>)`. For that reason, the exception you're seeing should be printed as `StopIteration: 3`, and the value is accessible through the attribute `value` on the exception object. If the generator is delegated to using the (also new) `yield from` syntax, it is the result. See [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) for details.

```
def f():
    return 1
    yield 2

def g():
    x = yield from f()
    print(x)

# g is still a generator so we need to iterate to run it:
for _ in g():
    pass
```

This prints `1`, but not `2`.

Answer (score 47):

The return value is not ignored, but generators only *yield* values, a `return` just ends the generator, in this case early. Advancing the generator never reaches the `yield` statement in that case.

Whenever a iterator reaches the 'end' of the values to yield, a `StopIteration` *must* be raised. Generators are no exception. As of Python 3.3 however, any `return` expression becomes the value of the exception:

```
>>> def gen():
...     return 3
...     yield 2
... 
>>> try:
...     next(gen())
... except StopIteration as ex:
...     e = ex
... 
>>> e
StopIteration(3,)
>>> e.value
3
```

Use the `next()` function to advance iterators, instead of calling `.__next__()` directly:

```
print(next(x))
```