# Yield vs generator expression - different type returned

Tags: python, generator, yield

There is this code:

```
def f():
  return 3
  return (i for i in range(10))

x = f()
print(type(x)) # int

def g():
  return 3
  for i in range(10):
    yield i

y = g()
print(type(y)) # generator
```

Why `f` returns `int` when there is return generator statement? I guess that `yield` and generator expression both returns generators (at least when the statement `return 3` is removed) but are there some other rules of function compilation when there is once generator expression returned and second time when there is `yield` keyword inside?

This was tested in Python 3.3

Comment: Your g() method is incorrect, you can't mix return and yield in the same function, you get an error. Paste the real code.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: You can, in fact, mix return and yield in the same function. In Python 3.2 and earlier, you cannot return a *value* (that is a `SyntaxError`), but in Python 3.3 and up, you even can do that too. See [Return in generator together with yield in Python 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16780002)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As *soon* as you use a `yield` statement in a function body, it becomes a generator. Calling a generator function just returns that generator object. It is no longer a normal function; the generator object has taken over control instead.

From the [`yield` expression documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

> Using a `yield` expression in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function.
>
> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function. The execution starts when one of the generator’s methods is called.

In a regular function, calling that function immediately switches control to that function body, and you are simply testing the result of the function, set by it's `return` statement. In a generator function, `return` still signals the end of the generator function, but that results in a `StopIteration` exception being raised instead. But until you call one of the 4 generator methods (`.__next__()`, `.send()`, `.throw()` or `.close()`), the generator function body is not executed at all.

For your specific function `f()`, you have a regular function, that *contains* a generator. The function itself is nothing special, other that that it exits early when `return 3` is executed. The generator expression on the next line stands on its own, it does not influence the function in which it is defined. You can define it without the function:

```
>>> (i for i in range(10))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x101472730>
```

Using a generator expression produces a generator object, just like using `yield` in a function, then calling that function produces a generator object. So you could have called `g()` in `f()` with the same result as using the generator expression:

```
def f():
    return 3
    return g()
```

`g()` is still a generator function, but using it in `f()` does *not* make `f()` a generator function too. Only `yield` can do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
def f():
  return 3
  return (i for i in range(10))
```

is the same as

```
def f():
  return 3
```

The second return statement never gets executed, just by having a generator expression within `f` **does not** make it a generator.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f():
  return 3
  #unreachable code below
  return (i for i in range(10))
```

I believe what you meant is:

```
def f():
  yield 3
  yield from (i for i in range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a generator doesn't make `f` a generator function.  A generator is just an object, and generator objects can be returned by any function.  If you want `f` to be a generator function, you have to use `yield` inside the function, as you did with `g`.