# Python function returns generator instead of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, generator

I wanted to play around with primes in Python and therefore use a function to create a `Sieve of Eratosthenes`:

```
def primes(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False
    return list(a)
```

In my opinion this function should definitely return a list but when I do `print(primes(1000))` I only get `<generator object primes at 0x0000000002C5C558>` as the output. When using `print(list(primes(1000)))` everything works as expected (the list of primes is printed).

**What am I missing?**

**Why does the function return a generator instead of a list?**

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the function as a generator and using `list()` on it only if you actually _do_ need a list.

Comment: You're hitting a new (and questionably useful) feature of 3.3. Earlier versions didn't allow this. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16780002/989121).

Comment: I modified my code locally to return the generator. It is really more convenient.

Comment: This also seems to occur if your function uses the await keyword at any point...at least on CircuitPython.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you used a [`yield` expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) in the function.

In the sieve, `a` is a mask, not the final list of primes produced. You don't want to return that list, really.

If you wanted the function to return a list and not act as a generator, collect the primes in the function:

```
def primes(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False
    primes = []

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            primes.append(i)
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False

    return primes
```

Comment: I was blind... :( not only blind but also unexperienced.

Comment: Holly cr... you beat me two times in the same question :D

Answer (score 1):

Martijn beat me to it. You are hitting the yield expression before the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return the list you can:

```
def primes(limit):
    result = []         # Store primes here.
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            result.appen(i)
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False
    return result      # return primes
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue and wanted to update you all. If the function yields at some point it returns a generator even if you expect a list. So you need to get rid of yields.

```
def get_list_or_generator(return_list=True):
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    if return_list:
        return items  # returns generator
    else:
        for item in items:
            yield item  # returns generator
```

And it works with `list(get_list_or_generator())` as a list because [casting to list iterates through the generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445597/is-there-any-shorthand-for-yield-all-the-output-from-a-generator)