# Is there any shorthand for 'yield all the output from a generator'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

Is there a one-line expression for:

```
for thing in generator:
    yield thing
```

I tried `yield generator` to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581332/converting-yield-from-statement-to-python-2-7-code is related

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Python 3.3+, you can use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380). For example,

```
>>> def get_squares():
...     yield from (num ** 2 for num in range(10))
... 
>>> list(get_squares())
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

It can actually be used with any iterable. For example,

```
>>> def get_numbers():
...     yield from range(10)
... 
>>> list(get_numbers())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> def get_squares():
...     yield from [num ** 2 for num in range(10)]
... 
>>> list(get_squares())
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

---

Unfortunately, Python 2.7 has no equivalent construct :'(

Comment: I don't think the helper function does exactly the same in Py2.7 as what `yield from` does in Py3.3. Calling this function just returns another generator object, so it is pretty similar to the built-in `iter`. If you call your `yield_from()` from within a function, this function will not automatically become a generator function, as will happen with `yield from`. As far as I [understand](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#motivation),  in Py2.7, you need to write the explicit for-loop as shown by the OP.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Yup, the helper function is not the same. But, you can delegate the generator to that function and it would make the code simpler, no?

Comment: No, I think the helper function is useless, since it does not yield from the calling function. As shown in the PEP, this `for i in generator: yield i` can not be factored out into a separate function. You just rewrote `iter` ... :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use a list comprehension to get all of the elements out of a generator (assuming the generator ends):

```
[x for x in generator]
```

Comment: would this negate some of the lazy properties of generators, i.e. convert its output to a list?

Comment: Absolutely.  By converting to a list you are allocating all of the memory necessary to warehouse the data "generated" by the generator.  Also, if the generator does not complete the above statement will never terminate.

Comment: No, that's the heavy cost of converting a generator into a memory representation.  I would suggest considering *why* you're converting from a generator to a list; in most instances you don't want to force the generator to evaluate until necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one-liner valid in Python 2.5+ as requested ;-):

```
for thing in generator: yield thing
```