# Equivalent of `return` for Python generators

Tags: python, coding-style, generator, yield

Sometimes, when rewriting recursive functions as generators, I miss the brevity of `return`.

```
"""
Returns a list of all length n strings that can be made out of a's and/or b's.
"""
def ab_star(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [""]

    results = []
    for s in ab_star(n - 1):
        results.append("a" + s)
        results.append("b" + s)

    return results
```

turns into

```
"""
Generator for all length n strings that can be made out of a's and/or b's.
"""
def ab_star(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield ""

    else:
        for s in ab_star(n - 1):
            yield "a" + s
            yield "b" + s
```

It's that `else` that bugs me. I wish there was a way to say "`yield`, and this is it, so exit the function". Is there a way?

Comment: Why not add after the first use of `yield` a `return`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't miss `return`, use it.

You can `return` right after you `yield`.

```
def ab_star(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield ""
        return
    for s in ab_star(n - 1):
        yield "a" + s
        yield "b" + s
```

---

An alternative is to use `return` in both cases, where the first case returns a sequence of length 1, and the second returns a generator-expression:

```
def ab_star(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ( "", )
    return ( c+s for s in ab_star(n - 1) for c in 'ab' )
```

This avoidance of `yield` avoids the limitation that you cannot use both `return <value>` and `yield` in the same function.

(This works in your case because your function doesn't *have to* be a generator. Since you only iterate over the results, it can also return a tuple.)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't.  When I wrote the ["Simple Generators PEP"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), I noted:

> ```
> Q. Then why not allow an expression on "return" too?
>
> A. Perhaps we will someday.  In Icon, "return expr" means both "I'm
>    done", and "but I have one final useful value to return too, and
>    this is it".  At the start, and in the absence of compelling uses
>    for "return expr", it's simply cleaner to use "yield" exclusively
>    for delivering values.
> ```

But that never gained traction.  Until it does ;-), you can make your generator look more like your first function by writing the first part as:

```
if n == 0:
    yield ""
    return
```

Then you can drop the `else:` statement and dedent the rest.

Comment: Oh, interesting. It looks from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3) like `return <expr>` actually means something different now. So I guess this will never happen?

Comment: Yes, in 3.3 `return <expr>` inside a generator gained a meaning, but a pretty obscure meaning unrelated to yielding values.  Instead it's related to the `StopIteration` exception, as the answer you linked to noted.