# Setting a limit on an infinite generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the below generator to be able to set an upper limit on the numbers returned.

Calling `list(it.takewhile(lambda x: x < 100, get_primes()))` returns a list of all primes under 100 as expected but `list(get_primes(100))` (which should return the same list in the same way) just returns with an empty list.

Obviously, I could include an `if n and candidate>=n: break` in the `for` loop but I'm mostly interested in why the `if n: return` construct doesn't work like I'm expecting it should. Shouldn't it just return the same `takewhile` iterator that works above? What am I overlooking here?

```
import itertools as it

def get_primes(n=None):
    """
    Generates primes to a max of n.

    >>> list(get_primes(100))
    [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
    """
    if n:
        return it.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, get_primes())
    composites = {}
    yield 2
    for candidate in it.count(3, 2):
        prime_factor = composites.pop(candidate, None)
        if prime_factor is None:
            yield candidate
            composites[candidate**2] = candidate
        else:
            composite = candidate + 2*prime_factor
            while composite in composites:
                composite += 2*prime_factor
            composites[composite] = prime_factor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
return it.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, get_primes())
```

Since this is a generator, it needs to `yield` these values instead of `return`ing them. Depending on your Python version, you might be able to use the [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) syntax.

The following might be useful as background reading: [Return in generator together with yield in Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

Comment: though replacing `return` with `yield` here won't have the expected behaviour (the generator will yield another generator as first value).

Comment: @isedev: `yield from` will be a straight replacement for `return` (a plain `yield`, of course, will not).

Comment: Sure, agreed if you can use `yield from`. Otherwise, the actual generator will need to be wrapped in a nested function so the outer function can `return` in both cases.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I had assumed that because the `return` statement would happen before any `yield` statement, it would happily return my takewhile iterator. From the linked thread, it appears that it doesn't work that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the line

```
return it.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, get_primes())
```

Since it's a generator, returning something stops the execution, and raises StopIteration(). You need to return the values in generator

```
#return all the values from generator
for a in it.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, get_primes())
    yield a

return
```