# I have a generator in my Python function; how can I return a modified list?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, generator, enumerate

A little background: I've been trying to code a "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm. At the request of some fine (and very patient) programmers on the StackOverflow Python chatroom, I did some reading on the `enumerate()` function and found a way to incorporate it into my code (yes, I'm very much a novice here). So far, my (workable; returns expected response) code looks like this:

```
def SieveErat(n):
    numbers = [False]*2+[True]*(n-1)

    for index, prime_candidate in enumerate(numbers):
        if prime_candidate == True:
            yield index
            for x in xrange(index*index, n, index):
                numbers[x] = False

primes = []

for x in SieveErat(150000):
    primes.append(x)

print primes[10002]
```

Needless to say, the `enumerate()` function makes coding this much, much less awkward than whatever nested loops I had before. However, I fear that I'm not understanding something about `enumerate()`, because when I tried to shorten this code by including the appending into the function, I kept getting errors- namely,

```
File "SievErat.py", line 13
        return numbers
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

I've also tried appending all the `True` elements inside the list `numbers` to a initialized list `primes`, but found no luck.

Any hints or advice would be very much welcomed.

Comment: um... your code doesn't have any `return numbers` in it, please show us the code that raises the error you are facing.

Comment: in python before 3.3 you cannot have `return <something>` as well as `yield` in the same function, in python 3.3+ [return means something entirely different in generator context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `enumerate` you are trying to return something in a generator which before python 3.3 is illegal, and [from 3.3+ it means something entirely different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

I'd recommend you leave your function a generator if you may use it without needing a list back, and if you want list results then just call `list()` on the return value:

```
primes = list(SieveErat(150000)) #this replaces loop with .append
```

But to understand what went wrong, if your function still has the `yield` statement in it then it must return a generator object, if you don't want it to return a generator object then remove the `yield` statement all together:

```
def SieveErat(n):
    numbers = [False]*2+[True]*(n-1)

    for index, prime_candidate in enumerate(numbers):
        if prime_candidate == True:
            #yield index #no yield statement if you want to return the numbers list
            for x in xrange(index*index, n, index):
                numbers[x] = False

    return numbers #return at end
```

However this would then return a list of `True` and `False` instead of the numbers that are True, you can instead hold a separate list with all the prime numbers and `.append` to it everytime you would `yield` something:

```
def SieveErat(n):
    numbers = [False]*2+[True]*(n-1)
    result = [] #start with no results
    for index, prime_candidate in enumerate(numbers):
        if prime_candidate == True:
            results.append(index) #instead of yield index
            for x in xrange(index*index, n, index):
                numbers[x] = False
    return results
```

But this feels like a step backwards from a generator, personally I'd just keep what you have posted and cast the result to a `list`.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your informative response, Tadhg- I have upvoted your response. If you wouldn't mind, could you expand on why you feel like eliminating the `yield` in lieu of an `append` (as you showed in your example) feels like a step backwards?

Comment: @daOnlyBG most of the references I have seen on generators (like the [official python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) work on changing from building a list to making a generator, to quote a part of that link _""but its builds the full list in memory. This is clearly not acceptable in our case, because we cannot afford to keep all n "10 megabyte" integers in memory.""_