# Unable to return a generator instance. why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, generator

I am using python 3.5.
When I tried to return a generator function instance and i am getting a StopIteration error. Why?

here is my code:

```
>>> def gen(start, end):
... '''generator function similar to range function'''
...    while start <= end:
...       yield start
...       start += 1
...
>>> def check(ingen, flag=None):
...    if flag:
...        for n in ingen:
...            yield n*2
...    else:
...        return ingen
...
>>> # Trigger else clause in check function
>>> a = check(gen(1,3))
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: <generator object gen at 0x7f37dc46e828>
```

It looks like the generator is somehow exhausted before the else clause is returns the generator.

It works fine with this function:

```
>>> def check_v2(ingen):
...     return ingen
...
>>> b = check_v2(gen(1, 3))
>>> next(b)
1
>>> next(b)
2
>>> next(b)
3
```

Comment: @martineau it's fine in Python 3

Comment: @wroniasty: From what I've just read, it fine only in Python 3.3+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, if `yield` is present in a function, then Python treats it as a generator. In a generator, any return will raise `StopIteration` with the returned value. This is a new feature in Python 3.3: see [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780113/2097780). `check_v2` works because it doesn't contain a `yield` and is therefore a normal function.

There are two ways to accomplish what you want:

- Change the `return` to a `yield` in `check`.
- Have the caller trap `StopIteration`, as shown below

  ```
  try:
      next(a)
  except StopIteration as ex:
      print(ex.value)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

When a generator hits its `return` statement (explicit or not) it raises `StopIteration`. So when you `return ingen` you end the iteration.

`check_v2` is not a generator, since it does not contain the `yield` statement, that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, if you return from a generator, it means the the generator has stopped yielding items, which raises a `StopIteration` whatever you return.

This means that `check` actually returns an empty iterator.

If you want to return the results of another generator, you can use `yield from` :

```
def check(ingen, flag=None):
    if flag:
        for n in ingen:
            yield n*2
    else:
        yield from ingen
```

Comment: Thank u for opening my eyes to the `yield from` syntax. +1

Comment: interestingly it's also with `yield from` that coroutines are implemented (were, actually, now it's a native opcode)

Answer (score 0):

See [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics):

> In a generator, the statement
>
> ```
> return value
> ```
>
> is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> raise StopIteration(value)
> ```
>
> except that, as currently, the exception cannot be caught by `except`
>   clauses within the returning generator.

This is a new feature in Python 3.3.