# Using return statement in generators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python, reading by the book Learning Python, and came across the section of using the `return` statement in generators, and I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around it.

It says that while using the `return` statement in a generator function, it will produce a `StopIteration` exception to be raised, effectively ending the iteration. If a `return` statement were actually to make the function return something, it would break the iteration protocol.

Here's the code sample

```
def geometric_progression(a, q):
    k = 0
    while True:
        result = a * q**k
        if result <= 100000:
            yield result
        else:
            return
        k += 1

for n in geometric_progression(2,5):
    print(n)
```

Can anyone please explain it, and also how to use it further in any other context. Provide extra examples, if you may.

Comment: Just think of it as stopping the iteration early. In this case, the condition `result <= 100000` stops the generator from yielding a result bigger than `100000`, which is kind of contrived, since you could have made the while-loop `while <= 100000` to achieve the same effect (with some appropriate initial value for `result`). Honestly, I don't think it's used very much, but there are cases where you want to stop iteration immediately where it might come in handy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return in generator together with yield in Python 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

Comment: @Chris_Rands -- FWIW, this is _slightly_ different than that question.  That is specifically asking what `return value` means whereas this is asking about bare return as well (and is therefore applicable to python2.x as well).  I agree though -- They're _very_ similar and I could understand if this ended up being closed as a dupe :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` in a generator is just syntactic sugar for `raise StopIteration`.  In python 3.3(?)+, you can also return a value (`return value` == `raise StopIteration(value)`).

As for why you'd want to put it there, obviously raising a `StopIteration` means that the generator will stop yielding items.  In other words, the generator is finished executing -- just like `return` signals the end of a function's execution.  Similarly, anything which is iterating over the generator (e.g. a `for` loop) will understand that it should stop trying to get values from the generator.

The `return value` bit was added to support some workflows using co-routines IIRC.  It's a pretty advanced feature but finds lots of usefulness in various async contexts.

Comment: So, here the `return` statement implies is to break from the iteration when it hits the needed specific value?

Comment: @phawk -- Yep.  Pretty much.