# How can I yield notifications and return a result from a function? (Python)

Tags: python, generator, yield, server-sent-events

I have to create a function that does some hard work in the internal calls. This function needs to be a generator because I'm using Server-Sent Events. So that, I want that this function notifies the progress of the calculations by using a "yield". After that, this function has to pass the result to the parent function in order to continue with other calculations.

I would like something like this:

```
def hardWork():
    for i in range(N):
        # hard work
        yield 'Work done: ' + str(i)

    # Here is the problem: I can't return a result if I use a yield
    return result             

def generator():
    # do some calculations
    result = hardWork()
    # do other calculations with this result
    yield finalResult
```

I found a solution that consists on yields a dictionary that tells if the function has finished or not, but the code to do this is pretty dirty.

Is there another solution?

Thank you!

## EDIT

I thought something like:

```
def innerFunction(gen):
    calc = 1

    for iteration in range(10):
        for i in range(50000):
            calc *= random.randint(0, 10)
        gen.send(iteration)

    yield calc


def calcFunction(gen):
    gen2 = innerFunction(gen)
    r = next(gen2)

    gen.send("END: " + str(r + 1))
    gen.send(None)


def notifier():
    while True:
        x = yield
        if x is None:
            return
        yield "Iteration " + x


def generator():
    noti = notifier()
    calcFunction(noti)
    yield from noti


for g in generator():
    print(g)
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3

Comment: I think you should really read about async functions as this is very close to what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Prior to Python3.5: generators

This solution also works for more recent Python versions, although `async def`, new in Python3.5, seems more fit for your usecase. *See next section*.

The values yielded by a generator are obtained by iterating or using `next`. The value returned at the end is stored in the `value` attribute of the `StopIteration` exception that indicates the end of the generator. Fortunately, it is not too hard to recover.

```
def hardWork():
    output = []

    for i in range(10):
        # hard work
        yield 'Doing ' + str(i)
        output.append(i ** 2)

    return output

def generator():
    # do some calculations
    work = hardWork()

    while True:
        try:
            print(next(work))
        except StopIteration as e:
            result = e.value
            break

    yield result
```

### Example

```
foo = generator()
print(next(foo))
```

### Output

```
Doing 0
Doing 1
Doing 2
Doing 3
Doing 4
Doing 5
Doing 6
Doing 7
Doing 8
Doing 9
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

## Python3.5+: `async def`

If you are running Python3.5+, what you are attempting seems perfectly fit for an event loop using awaitable functions.

```
import asyncio

async def hardWork():
    output = []

    for i in range(10):
        # do hard work
        print('Doing ', i)
        output.append(i**2)

        # Break point to allow the event loop to do other stuff on the side
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    return output

async def main():
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(hardWork(), timeout=None)
    print(result)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

### Output

```
Doing  0
Doing  1
Doing  2
Doing  3
Doing  4
Doing  5
Doing  6
Doing  7
Doing  8
Doing  9
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to embed your functionality in a class.

```
def Worker:

    def hardWork(self):
        self.Finished = False
        for i in range(10):
            yield 'Work done: ' + str(i)
        self.Finished = True
        self.Result = 'result'

    def generator(self):
        while (not self.Finished):
            print(next(self.hardWork()))
        return self.Result
```

This will have the functionality you want without having to worry about programming your logic around exception throw-catch logic.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.3 introduces [`yield from` for generator delegation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380), which is pretty much exactly what you're asking for. `yield from` allows the main generator to delegate functionality to another function which also contains `yield` statements, like this:

```
def hardWork():
    for i in range(N):
        # hard work
        yield 'Work done so far: ' + str(i)

    # With this construction, you can still return a result after the `yield`s
    return result

def generator():
    # here's the new construction that makes it all work:
    result = yield from hardWork()

    # do other calculations with this result
    yield finalResult
```