# Base case of recursive generator: yield or return

Tags: python, recursion, generator

Why is there a difference between using `return` and `yield` in a recursive generator's base case?

As a simple example, this function uses `yield` and does what I want ([Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)):

```py
def product(x):
        if not x:
            yield tuple()
        else:
            head, *tail = x
            for i in head:
                for j in product(tail):
                    yield (i, ) + j

g = product([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print([i for i in g])

#[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

However, after changing `yield tuple()` to `return tuple()`, what I get is an empty list:

```py
def product(x):
        if not x:
            return tuple()
        else:
            head, *tail = x
            for i in head:
                for j in product(tail):
                    yield (i, ) + j

g = product([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print([i for i in g])

#[]
```

Writing `return [tuple()]` does not do the trick either:

```py
def product(x):
        if not x:
            return [tuple()]
        else:
            head, *tail = x
            for i in head:
                for j in product(tail):
                    yield (i, ) + j

g = product([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print([i for i in g])

#[]
```

Comment: Its no longer a generator if you use `return`

Comment: Once you use `return`, the function is stopped and not called again, whereas with `yield`, it's called from the `for` loop for every entry in the list.

Comment: It is still a generator with a return statement see [PEP 255 -- Simple Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/#specification-return).  However,  the return is signaling a stop iteration exception error for the generator i.e.  "... return <something> in a generator is equivalent to raise StopIteration(<something>)".    from [Return in generator together with yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return in generator together with yield in Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3)

Comment: It sort of does, yes. It might be helpful, however, to learn the reason behind why calling return from a generator raises `StopIteration`. In particular, why do generators treat the last element of the sequence they produce as special while iterators do not mark that last value? Also, is there a way to rewrite my example so that it uses `return` and `yield form`?