# function is still a generator if "yield" used in a if clause

Tags: python

if you look at the function below, you might see something strange

```
def might_be_generator(is_generator: bool = False):
    if is_generator:
        for i in range(5):
            yield i
    else:
        return list(range(5))
```

Now we will call this function with `is_generator=True` parameter:

```
>>> might_be_generator(True)
<generator object might_be_generator at 0x7f717a2396d0>
>>> list(might_be_generator(True))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(might_be_generator(True))
<class 'generator'>
```

Sounds like it's true
But let's try this with `is_generator=False` parameter:

```
>>> might_be_generator()
<generator object might_be_generator at 0x7f717a2396d0> # What is going on !?
>>> list(might_be_generator())
[]
>>> type(might_be_generator())
<class 'generator'>
```

**What happened?**
still a `generator`. shouldn't be a `list`?

Comment: Having a `yield` anywhere in the function makes it a generator.  If you return without actually yielding anything at runtime, it's just an empty generator.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3 for an explanation of what `return` means in a generator function and how to get the returned value after the generator has been exhausted.