# Generator type hints in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Looking in [the documentation for generator typing](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) I saw the generic type

```
   Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]
```

I expected to only get a "yield type" for my generator.

What are the two others used for?

Answer (score 2):

Generators can not only yield values to their callers, but callers can also send values in the other direction, see [Yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) or, e.g., [What is the purpose of the "send" function on Python generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302530). The type of the value sent to the generator is defined by the `SendType`.

The meaning of the `ReturnType` is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) (see also [Return in generator together with yield](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16780002)):

> When a generator or coroutine function returns, a new StopIteration instance is raised, and the value returned by the function is used as the value parameter to the constructor of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

So you can go ahead with something like this :

```
from typing import Generator

def generate_numbers(n: int) -> Generator[None, None, int]:
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

# Usage
numbers_generator: Generator[int, None, None] = generate_numbers(5)

for number in numbers_generator:
    print(number)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your example rather use `Generator[int, None, None]`?

Answer (score 1):

They refer to the three interactions you can have with a generator. The first is well known, yielding objects.

The third is, that just like a normal function, generators can also return values. This value is what is returned by `yield from gen()` expressions (as opposed to yielded). More formally, when a generator returns it raises `StopIteration(return_value)`. This exception can be caught when calling `next(gen)`.

```py
def gen():
    if False: yield
    return 'return'

try:
    next(gen())
except StopIteration as exc:
    result = exc.value
assert result == 'return'
```

The second is much less well known. As well as yielding objects, generators can also be sent objects. They are sent using the `send` function (`gen.send(value)`), and are the result of a yield expression (`sent = yield value`). NB. A generator must have yielded at least once before you can use the `send()` function.

Example:

```py
class Yield: pass
class Send: pass
class Return: pass

def gen_func():
    yield_object = Yield()
    return_object = Return()
    print(f'yielding {yield_object=}')
    send_object: Send = yield yield_object
    print(f'sent {send_object=}')
    yield Yield()
    print(f'returning {return_object=}')
    return return_object

def main():
    gen: typing.Generator[Yield, Send, Return] = gen_func()

    y0: Yield = next(gen)
    y1: Yield = gen.send(Send())
    result: Return = yield from gen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list(main())
```